# Mime-Type exception while enumerating azure rest call response

Tags: azure, odata, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am using Azure SDK Oct 2012. ODataLib dependency in the Storage Client Library for .NET is resolved through the ODataLib (version 5.0.2). When I fire a query on azure tables I get following exception:

```
A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type 
    of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/atom+xml;type=feed,
    application/atom+xml, application/json;odata=verbose' matches the content type
   'text/xml;charset=utf-8'.
```

When I used **Fidler** to track the header values of HTTP,

for Request it was

```
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/xml
```

for Response it was

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
```

I am sure it is happening because of the Proxy at my organisation. (bcs same code works fine with no Proxy).
So can anyone help me how to fix this problem?

1) Is there a way to set the Content-Type while firing query?

2) Or ODataLib is does not handle Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the problem as follows.

With the help of **"Costomize Rules"** option under "**Rules**" menu of **Fidler**, open "**CustomRules.js**" file. There exists a function called "**OnBeforeResponse**". Add below code inside this function to change response Content-Type before data is given to application (API).

```
if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "text/xml")){
    // Remove the content-type header (text/xml)
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("Content-Type");

    // Replace Content-Type with the new type
    oSession.oResponse["Content-Type"] = "application/atom+xml";        

}
```

Answer (score 2):

ODataLib uses the Content-Type header to determine which format the response should be parsed as. The "text/xml" MIME type is not a valid content type per OData, which is why you're getting the error.

If you have a proxy that is turning "application/xml" into "text/xml", then you'll need to undo that at some layer before it gets passed to ODataLib. I don't have any experience with the Storage Client Library for .Net, so I'm not sure what level of control you have over modifying the response headers before the payload is parsed by ODataLib, but if you can override the response's Content-Type header directly, you could just change "text/xml" back to "application/xml" (or "application/atom+xml").

If you were using ODataLib directly (or if the library you're using on top of it exposes the IODataResponseMessage implementation), you could just modify the implementation of IODataResponseMessage.GetHeader() to return "application/xml" anytime it would try to return "text/xml" when the input to the method is "Content-Type".

Also, to answer to your first question, the way to set the content type at request time is via the Accept header, which is already correct in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you said we tried to change the header Content-Type field just after receiving the response and before enumerating it (used fidler's CustomRules option). And it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution proposed may work, a More simple solution would be to use HTTPS to avoid having the proxy replace the headers. If your requirement is to still use HTTP the Storage Client code could be modified to manually replace this header prior to being parsed by the OData library (see HttpResponseAdapterMessage.cs GetHeader function).

joe